# JBoss Fuse / Apache camel won't resolve language js (javascript) for bundle

Tags: java, javascript, bundle, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am deploying an osgi application to JBoss Fuse / Apache Camel and the javascript language doesn't want to resolve.

This error appears in the log:

```
ERROR | BluePrinntContainerImpl | Bundle my-service is waiting for dependencies
[(&(language=js)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver))]
```

I recently added a `.javaScript()` expression definition to a `.choice()` statement:

```
.choice()
    .when()
    .javaScript("request.body.updateSeq > exchange.getProperty('PrevUpdateSeq') + 1")
    .to("dosomething")
```

Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where camel version is `2.10.0.redhat-60024`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the javascript language not being registered.

I modified some code I found on servicemix nabble to make sure the javascript engine is registered and has the key (language name)  `js` instead of `ECMAScript`.

Same goes for `groovy` (instead of `Groovy`), although please note: this part is untested.

How to fix:

1. Copy the `Activator` code from [this page](http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/help-How-to-use-javascript-with-camel-in-ServiceMix-td5718477.html) and add it as a new class in your project.
2. Modify the `register()` method in `BundleLanguageResolver` as follows:

   ```
   public void register() {
       try
       {
           String language = factory.getLanguageName();

           // Hack to register languages correctly
           if ("ECMAScript".equals(language)) language = "js";
           if ("Groovy".equals(language)) language = "groovy";

           Hashtable<String, Object> properties =
                   new Hashtable<String, Object>();

           properties.put("language", language);

           reg = bundle.getBundleContext().registerService(
                   LanguageResolver.class,
                   new ScriptLanguageResolver(), properties);

           LOG.debug("Register LanguageResolver: " + language);
       } catch(Exception e)
       {
           LOG.warn("Cannot register LanguageResolver: " + e.getClass().getName(), e);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add the class you just created (e.g. `com.my.Activator`) to the manifest as a `Bundle-Activator`. The maven-bundle-plugin line can look like this:

   ```
   <Bundle-Activator>com.my.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
   ```

Perhaps there is another solution, but in the meantime this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

And you have installed the features

```
features:install camel-script
```

And there may be a special for javascript named something along the lines of:

```
features:install camel-script-javascript
```

Comment: Hi Claus, thanks, I initially had some problems getting those features installed as dependencies of my own feature, so I manually installed them in my profile - they are now installed, however I still get the error. Could it be due to this I wonder: http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/help-How-to-use-javascript-with-camel-in-ServiceMix-td5718477.html org.apache.camel.script.osgi.Activator in v2.10.0.readhat-60024 is missing `languageResolvers`...

Comment: Ok, I have a solution, it's due to `RhinoScriptEngineFactory` returning value from `getLanguageName()` that is not `js`!! It returns `ECMAScript` and is not being found by the language resolver. I'll tidy up my code and show you later :)

Comment: Ah you are welcome to log a JIRA at Apache Camel, so we can detect ECMAScript as js name as well.

Comment: No worries: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7122. Please see my other answer for a workaround in 2.10.0.

Comment: Update from jira, looks like this is fixed in 2.13

Answer (score 0):

For the time being (I'm using Camel 2.16.5) adding google's scriptengine as a dependency does the trick:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.scriptengines</groupId>
    <artifactId>scriptengines-javascript</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```